# How to convert timestamp to date only where timestamp is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to join two tables relating to the number of customers get how many points in each ops. However, when I convert timestamp date to date it converts 0 value to 1970/01/01 but I don't want to change 0 value to date format.

Userpts Table:

```
UseriD  Timestamp     Points       Ops
567     0                -20        x                                   
456     0                -20        y                                   
345    1470129513         50        b                                   
345    0                 -40        y                                   
123    1470058344         45        a                                   
123    0                 -30        x                                   
123   1470129513          40        a
```

MID table

```
   Userid   MID
    123    666  
    345    666  
    567    444  
    456    444
```

Out

```
UseriD  Timestamp     Points       Ops   MID

567     0                -20        x   444                             
456     0                -20        y   444                             
345    2016/08/02         50        b   666                             
345    0                 -40        y   666                             
123    2016/08/01         45        a   666                         
123    0                 -30        x   666                             
123   2016/08/02          40        a   666
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, unix timestamp `0` does map to timestamp `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

`0` is not a valid date, so you can't have that in the column. An alternative would be to return `null` instead:

```
case when timestamp > 0 then from_unixtime(timestamp) end as new_timestamp
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to do with the case clause, but I was figuring out that could we stop the conversion of the timestamp on a particular condition. I want 0 in my output inplace of null. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest `from_unixtime(nullif(timestamp, 0))` instead of the `case` expression.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Results are not coming as expected, Null is appearing wherever the timestamp is having 0 value

Comment: @Sid . . . `NULL` is a better choice than `0`.  You don't want to mix date/timestamp values in a column with numbers.  Use `NULL`.